# Existence of invariant Borel measures in infinite-dimensional separable Banach spaces.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Borel  measure in an infinite-dimensional  separable Banach space $X$.

We say that $h \in B$ is admissible(in the sense of quasiinvariance) for the measure $\mu$ if measures $\mu$ and $\mu_h$ are equivalent, where $\mu_h$ (called $h$-shift of $\mu$) is defined by $\mu_h(A)=\mu(A-h)$ for $A \in B(X)$.

A set of all admissible translatins (in the sense of quasiinvariance)for the measure $\mu$ we denote by $Q(\mu)$.

We say that $h \in B$ is admissible(in the sense of invariance) for the measure $\mu$ if measures $\mu$ and $\mu_h$ coincide.

A set of all admissible translatins(in the sense of invariance) for the measure $\mu$ we denote by $I(\mu)$.

Question.  Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure in $X$ such that $Q(\mu)$ is everywhere dence in $X$(for example, any Gaussian measure). Does there exist a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure $\lambda$ in $X$ such that  $I(\lambda)=Q(\mu)$  and measures $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are equivalent?